# How can I set a timeout on Dataflow?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Composer to run my Dataflow pipeline on a schedule.  If the job is taking over a certain amount of time, I want it to be killed.  Is there a way to do this programmatically either as a pipeline option or a DAG parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it as a pipeline config option, but here is an idea.

You could launch a taskqueue task with countdown set to your timeout value. When the task does launch, you could check to see if your task is still running:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list

If it is, you can call update on it with job state `JOB_STATE_CANCELLED`

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#jobstate

This is done through the `googleapiclient` lib: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/discovery/v1

Here is an example of how to use it

```
class DataFlowJobsListHandler(InterimAdminResourceHandler):

    def get(self, resource_id=None):
        """
        Wrapper to this:
        https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list
        """
        if resource_id:
            self.abort(405)
        else:
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
            service = discovery.build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
            project_id = app_identity.get_application_id()
            _filter = self.request.GET.pop('filter', 'UNKNOWN').upper()

            jobs_list_request = service.projects().jobs().list(
                projectId=project_id,
                filter=_filter)  #'ACTIVE'
            jobs_list = jobs_list_request.execute()

            return {
                '$cursor': None,
                'results': jobs_list.get('jobs', []),
            }
```